# Actively blurring everything behind a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, blur

There are tons of JS libraries SVG/CSS tricks that make the background of a div layer blurred. But what they all do is to blur a single frame and unmask the blurred part over the unblurred layer. If you drag a new element such as a text or an image behind a layer always-on-top, it won't be actively blur whatever behind it. I like to achieve a function that works just as Windows 7 Aero theme.

Comment: Just update the blur as necessary? You can build this on top of pretty much any blur library.

Comment: I haven't seen any example in action. I'm not even sure of its feasibility.

Comment: I tried many related libraries that did not provide me with this particular solution. And I did not assume this is a platform where you have to work collaboratively or somewhere you'll limited to asking 'where is the mistake in my code' kind of questions. Perhaps I'm only in need of a library that some people know, or even someone to discuss the feasibility of what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: A quick Google search turns up a number of solutions that actually do this. Either ways this is offtopic if it's asking us to find an off-site tool or a script.

Comment: The http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ is a great place to discuss things, or ask about tools for that matter. As Nit points out, SO is not about recommending stuff.

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible currently (mid-2014) in IE10+ with SVG content using SVG filters and the backgroundImage pseudo-input. No other browser supports filter operations on a content's background as specified in the SVG 1.1 spec.

This is not possible anywhere on generic HTML content.